# How to handle user without entering the special character in query?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How to handle special character in query .My application is crash user add `:?.?);;;;`. I need to handle these characters. I want to show alert if user add this characters in text field?

Actually the problem is when user add this test in this field `:?.?);;;;`. I create the folder in director. Due to unable to create directory. It crash. How to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code with a Regex:

```
 $('input').keyup(function() {

    if(/[^\w]/g.test($(this).val())) {

        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\w]/g, ""));

        alert('Don\'t enter special characters!');

    }

});
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/VwXRg/

Comment: if i have this  <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text" class="documentName_h" autocorrect="off">

Comment: what i will write instead of this.$('input').keyup(function()

Comment: Use `$('input#text-12')` or `$('input[name="text-12"]')` as selector. If you use `$('input')`, the validation will be applied on all inputs on that page.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to somehow prevent the filename to contain such special characters. I suggest  to remove these characters via `replace`

Replace the special characters like `, / ? : @ & = + $ #` via an replace statement like `text = text.replace('/[,\/?:@&=+$#]/g', '');`

Or do the opposite thing and just specify which characters would be allowed, which would be all alphanumeric values `a-zA-Z0-9` and `_` which is euqivalent to `\w`. The code for this would look like `text = text.replace('/[^\w]/g', '');`. Maybe you want to allow more chars, just add them after the `\w`.